# how to create acetream regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get the acestream url from text.
How can I create this regex?

here an example:

```
    <div class="md"><blockquote>
<p>acestream://5a2686630a7f6422d6edf02a197cbdf7c2695175</p>
</blockquote>

<p>720p version stuttering a lot for me, and I&#39;ve got lightning connection speed</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this if URL contains hexadecimal characters :

```
$subject = '<div class="md"><blockquote>
<p>acestream://5a2686630a7f6422d6edf02a197cbdf7c2695175</p>
</blockquote>
<p>720p version stuttering a lot for me, and I&#39;ve got lightning connection speed</p>
</div>';

if (preg_match('~acestream://[0-9a-f]+~', $subject, $matches)) {
    echo reset($matches);
}
```

Outputs :

```
acestream://5a2686630a7f6422d6edf02a197cbdf7c2695175
```

Or you could replace `[0-9a-f]` by `[\w]` to get letters, digits or underscore.